# "sudo: apt: command not found" when trying to deploy a django app with aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, command, sudo, apt

I am trying to deploy my first Django app with AWS. I did everything until I reached the step of using sudo in the ec2 environmental setup. when I try to run sudo apt update I get `sudo: apt: command not found`.

[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using **Amazon Linux 2023**, which uses `yum` (or now `dnf` as well). `apt` is for `Ubuntu`. So you have to use `dnf` in your case.

```
sudo dnf update
```

Comment: when I do `sudo dnf install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx gunicorn curl`, I get `No match for argument: python3-dev
No match for argument: libpq-dev
No match for argument: postgresql
No match for argument: postgresql-contrib
No match for argument: gunicorn
`

Comment: @ItayLador I would suggest making new question for the new issue.